# Can't make log in in Python 3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x, xampp, pymysql

I have created a database and needs to check that one for corresponding user name and password... if it is there it should print "success" else not...

I tried many ways, it will print only if the there is a correct username and password... else it shows nothing.

It does not show can't log in or error. It only exits with 0 error without any display.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import pymysql

# Open database connection
db = pymysql.connect("localhost","root","","text" )

# prepare a cursor object using cursor() method
cursor = db.cursor()
eg = input("What's your user name? ")
password = input("What's your user password? ")

sql = ("SELECT * FROM login WHERE name = '%s' AND password= '%s' " % (eg,password))

try:
    # Execute the SQL command
    cursor.execute(sql)
    results = None
    # Fetch all the rows in a list of lists.
    results = cursor.fetchall()
    try:
        if results is not None:
            for row in results:
                id = row[0]
                name = row[1]
                password = row[2]
                print("login success")
    except:
        print("Error you arenot in the planet dude sign up first")

except:
    print("Error you arenot in the planet dude sign up first")

# disconnect from server
db.close()
```

Comment: You shouldn't be saving passwords in the database, hash then using skating like passlib first. https://bitbucket.org/ecollins/passlib/wiki/Home

Answer (score 0):

Something seems off with the indentation, try the following segment:

```
try:
    # Execute the SQL command
    cursor.execute(sql)
    results = None
    # Fetch all the rows in a list of lists.
    results = cursor.fetchall()
    try:
        if results is not None :
            for row in results:
                id = row[0]
                name = row[1]
                password= row[2]
                print ("login success")
    except:
    print("Error you arenot in the planet dude sign up first")

except:
    print ("Error you are not in the planet dude sign up first")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for row in results:

   id = row[0]
   name = row[1]
   password= row[2]
   print ("login success")
```

Should be

```
success = False
for row in results:

   db_id = row[0]
   db_name = row[1]
   db_password= row[2]

   if db_name == eg and db_password == password:
       success = True
       print ("login success")
```

The variables created from `row[1]` and `row[2]` need to be different from the `eq` and `password` variables created above. Once that is done, you just need to compare them to see if they match up.

You can check the success variable later on to perform an action only if the login process was successful or not successful.

Comment: tries as you said CDspace ,,,butif we enters right username and password its moves to except

Comment: Try removing the try except clauses, so you can see what error you're getting.

Comment: I'd mistyped it. It should be eg not eq.

Comment: but i have doubts........,,i got correct answer when that "if" => " if success == False: print("error:sign up first")" outside the "for" .. when i placed in the 'FOR' i doesn't gives answer. logically the success will be false if it is inside the for loop or outside the for loop so it should have to print error when i places in the "for",but it doesn't gives error when i placed inside the for loop